# How display encrypted image using BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, encryption

I'm using BitmapImage as Source to an Image control in WPF.

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
bi.UriSource = new Uri(strFilePath);
bi.EndInit();
return bi;
```

Now I've encrypted this image and planning to use this encrypted image when creating instance of BitmapImage. How do I do this?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean with using the encrypted image when creating instance of BitmapImage?  Do you want to display the encrypted image or what do you want to do?

Comment: Hi it's a normal JPG/TIF file that contain sensitive information, encrypted using Rijndael and saved to the disk. I want to display this Image decrypted on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! Answer was pretty simple. I should have used StreamSource.

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
bi.StreamSource = decryptedImageStream;
bi.EndInit();
```